# android recycler view retrieving data from firebase database

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

Im trying to retrieve data from the firebase database using recycler view, but I keep getting this error saying:

> Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.poppy.UserInformation

Can someone help me solve this?

Adapter Class

```
public class postAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<UserInformation> posts;

    public postAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<UserInformation> posts) {
        this.context = context;
        this.posts = posts;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.card,parent,false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.text.setText(posts.get(position).getPost());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return posts.size();
    }
}
```

Model class

```
public class UserInformation {

    public String post_text;
    public String id;



    public UserInformation(String post_text,String id) {
        this.post_text = post_text;
        this.id=id;
    }

    //public UserInformation (){}

    //Getter
    public String getPost() {
        return post_text;
    }
    public String getId(){return id;}
}
```

NewsFeed class

```
public class NewsFeedFragment extends Fragment {

    View root;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    postAdapter postAdapter;
    String firebaseAuth;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    ArrayList<UserInformation> postsArray;

    public NewsFeedFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        root=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_news_feed, container, false);

        init();

        return root;
    }

    private void init() {

        recyclerView=root.findViewById(R.id.recycler_newsfeed);

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager=new GridLayoutManager(getContext(),1);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        postsArray=new ArrayList<UserInformation>();
        postAdapter=new postAdapter(getContext(),postsArray);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(postAdapter);

        firebaseAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
        databaseReference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Posts").child(firebaseAuth);

        databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                if(snapshot.exists()){

                    for (DataSnapshot postsnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()){

                        UserInformation upload = postsnapshot.getValue(UserInformation.class);
                        

                        postsArray.add(upload);
                        recyclerView.invalidate();
                    }
                    postAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

//Firebase Json

```
    {
  "Posts": {
    "SnUFcmk8Llcy7xwWJ5d1fpp47wx2": {
      "-Nc-G0KCloNLkDBzOauf": "I'm here in my backyard with my Lamborghini ♡",
      "-Nc-GBc67pArbwZj_bxV": "Hey I'm here coding and it's fun yall ☺"
    },
    "Ym0gl0vBzUV1omI7ncOeU9NdZWU2": {
      "-Nc5_A1W2dCn5rMGiZsP": "hey yellow"
    }
  },
  "Users": {
    "PMJvIPKaEbR0vlgmFlIhvmvCHC92": {
      "email": "lisa@yahoo.com",
      "firstname": "Lisa",
      "lastname": "jim"
    },
    "SnUFcmk8Llcy7xwWJ5d1fpp47wx2": {
      "email": "ssky33@ymail.com",
      "firstname": "Sky",
      "lastname": "star"
    },
    "Ym0gl0vBzUV1omI7ncOeU9NdZWU2": {
      "email": "jjj@gmail.com",
      "firstname": "Joan",
      "lastname": "Lee"
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to see if the model class had any issues, but everything seems to be fine to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code reads the data from this path in the database:

```
databaseReference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Posts").child(firebaseAuth);
```

While you didn't share the data, given that the path is `/Posts/$uid` it seems that this path contains the data for one user. But then in the `onDataChange`, you do:

```
for (DataSnapshot postsnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()){
    UserInformation upload = postsnapshot.getValue(UserInformation.class);
    ...
```

So you loop over the child nodes **under** `/Posts/$uid` and try to read a `UserInformation` object from each of them. But if there's only one user's information at `/Posts/$uid`, that means that you're trying to interpret each property of that user's information as a full `UserInformation`, which explains the error message.

The solution is to remove the loop, and only read the one user's information:

```
databaseReference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Posts").child(firebaseAuth);

databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        if(snapshot.exists()){
            UserInformation upload = postsnapshot.getValue(UserInformation.class);            

            postsArray.add(upload);
            recyclerView.invalidate();
        }
        postAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
        throw error.toException(); // Never ignore errors
    }
});
```

---

**Update**: Based on the JSON you posted, the `/Posts/$uid` holds this data:

```
{
  "Posts": {
    "SnUFcmk8Llcy7xwWJ5d1fpp47wx2": {
      "-Nc-G0KCloNLkDBzOauf": "I'm here in my backyard with my Lamborghini ♡",
      "-Nc-GBc67pArbwZj_bxV": "Hey I'm here coding and it's fun yall ☺"
    },
    "Ym0gl0vBzUV1omI7ncOeU9NdZWU2": {
      "-Nc5_A1W2dCn5rMGiZsP": "hey yellow"
    }
  },
  ...
```

So inside your loop, this is the key/value pair for the `postsnapshot`:

```
"-Nc-G0KCloNLkDBzOauf": "I'm here in my backyard with my Lamborghini ♡"
```

There is no way for the `postsnapshot.getValue(UserInformation.class)` call to automatically map the information in that snapshot to the class you provide. The automatic mapping looks for two child properties in the value, one named `post` and one named `id`. But all it finds in the snapshot is a string value. Since the string value does not match the structure of your `UserInformation` class, you get the error you shared.

You can get the correct values from the snapshot with:

```
String id = postsnapshot.getKey();
String post = postSnapsot.getValue(String.class);
```

And then you can construct a `UserInformation` from it yourself.

Comment: the user has multiple posts so that's why I used the loop. Do I still have to remove it?

Comment: That depends. Please edit your question to show the data under `/Posts/$uid` (as text, no screenshots). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: I edited the code and added the Json file

Comment: Ah yeah, that clarifies indeed. I added an update.

Comment: I solved it. Can you take a look to see if its the correct way. Thank you

Comment: Good to hear you got it working. Since that's an implementation of what I said, please don't post it as a separate answer.